# ConcurrentModiciationException when adding an element to list while iterating

Tags: java, android

I have this code in my adapter which displays a list of schools. There is also a search filter. Whenever the search filter has a value the list must show schools that contains the letters of search filter. Here is my code -

```
public boolean refreshAdapter() {
        List<School> schools = cache().getSchools();
        if (schoolList != null && !schoolList.isEmpty()) {
            schoolList .clear();
        }

        schoolList = schools;

        for (School school: schoolList) {

            String name = school.getName();
            String address = vehicle.getAddress();

            if (name.contains(searchFilterText)|| address.contains(searchFilterText)) {
                schoolList.add(school);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (schoolList!= null) {
            return schoolList.isEmpty();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How can I get this code running without concurrent modification exception? I tried using ListIterator but did not help me

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop you are trying to create? From reading the code, it appears that you are trying to filter the list by name or address matching the search string, correct?

Comment: @JustinAlbano yes i am trying to filter the list by name or address in the loop

Answer (score 2):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` originates because the `schoolList` list is being modified within the process of iterating through that list. An alternative would be iterate the `schools` list instead and make the additions to the `schoolList`, which separates the list being iterated from the one being modified:

```
schoolList = new ArrayList<>();

for (School school: schools) {

    String name = school.getName();
    String address = vehicle.getAddress();

    if (name.contains(searchFilterText)|| address.contains(searchFilterText)) {
        schoolList.add(school);
    }
}
```

Another alternative (using JDK 8 or above) is to filter the `schools` list and capture the result into `schoolList`:

```
schoolList = schools.stream()
    .filter(school -> school.getName().contains(searchFilterText) || school.getAddress().contains(searchFilterText))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Based on the current state of the code, it appears that you will be re-adding elements to the `schoolList`, because it already contains those elements, hence why you are iterating over them. The code examples above result in lists that only contain the matching elements. If it desired to have the matching elements re-added to the `schoolList`, as in the original question, you can replace the following line in the first example

```
schoolList = new ArrayList<>();
```

with

```
schoolList = new ArrayList<>(school);
```

This will create a copy of the `school` list and store it in `schoolList` before the iteration begins.

Be careful if this is the intended behavior, as it may cause an infinite loop. For example, in the original question, had a `ConcurrentModificationException` not been thrown, if you add a `School` object that matches the condition (`name.contains(searchFilterText)|| address.contains(searchFilterText)`), it will also be iterated later on, which in turn would match the condition, and be re-added. This process would repeat infinitely. For example, suppose the only element in the `schoolList` matches the condition, the following would be the results contained in `schoolList` after each iteration:

Iteration 0:

```
matching school A    <-- Current element of iteration
matching school A    <-- [newly added element]
```

Iteration 1:

```
matching school A
matching school A    <-- Current element of iteration
matching school A    <-- [newly added element]
```

Iteration 2:

```
matching school A
matching school A
matching school A    <-- Current element of iteration
matching school A    <-- [newly added element]
```

And so on, infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ConcurrentModificationException`-s because you are iterating through a list while adding things to it. This is, in general, prohibited because adding stuff through iteration is confusing. In some cases, the programmers want the iteration to iterate through the recently added item, sometimes not. So java forces us to do either of these things explicitly.

You can fix it with a temporary list that stores the items you want to add to the list.

#### Step 1: find the items you want to add.

```
List<School> tempSchoolList = new ArrayList<>(); // this is the new list

// most of the things below comes from the original code
schoolList = schools;

for (School school: schoolList) {

    String name = school.getName();
    String address = vehicle.getAddress();
    if (name.contains(searchFilterText)|| address.contains(searchFilterText)) {
        tempSchoolList.add(school); // add the new list to the temp school list
    }
}
```

#### Step 2: add the items from the temp list to the original

```
schoolList.addAll(tempSchoolList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this Exception occurs because you must not add elements to the collection while iterating it. Did you get confused with `schools` and `shoolList`? Giving them more reasonable names can help a lot!

To do it correctly, you have to build a new filtered list (I commented the lines I changed)

```
    // this is the new filtered list
    schoolList = new ArrayList<>();

    // iterate the original list
    for (School school: schools) {

        String name = school.getName();
        String address = vehicle.getAddress();

        if (name.contains(searchFilterText)|| address.contains(searchFilterText)) {
             // add it to filtered list
            schoolList.add(school);
        }
    }
```